# React: Trying to import a javascript file from node_modules from a package I have installed but cannot be recognised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, import, node-modules

I am trying to import a file from react-validation but I am met with the following **warning** which isn't allowing the import:

> Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'react-validation/build/form'

This file does exist in my node_modules folder since I installed the package via `npm i react-validation` and I clearly see the folder is there.

I tried import in different ways, for example: `import Form from 'react-validation/build/form` but still not working.

Comment: Run `npm ls react-validation`. Also are you using TypeScript or just regular JS?

Comment: @mikemaccana This is regular javascript, I'll try that now thanks.

Comment: BTW you'd normally just import the package name, eg `import { Form } from "react-validation"` - the JS file inside `react-validation`  to load will be determined by the `react-validation`'s `package.json` file.

Comment: I made those changes but VScode is showing that "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-validation' "

Comment: That module is outdated by several years, please don't use it. I cannot reproduce your error (only by not installing it, obviously) but I'm getting tons of console errors and a blank screen. You can try to use it with React 16 but I don't see how that's useful. Pick a different validation module.

Comment: Oh really because I was working on a team project a few months ago and the people handling the front-end used this with no problem, I was just trying to follow their process as close as possible for self-learning purposes.

Comment: Ouch yes @React_validatorMan - 5 years is a really long time https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation! This isn't an answer, but Chris is right - you shouldn't be using this library

Comment: Wow didn't know that, I removed those elements for now and currently just working fine without front-end validations but will use a more modern package when I get round to it. Thanks for all the help guys!